# how to show result using multiple Order by descending using linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am having 3 criteria. I want to order these 3 types.

1. Who Paid with Master User
2. Who Update their Post Latest Date
3. Who Paid with Sub Master User

which one is having count it will come to top 15 Jobs.

My code here:

```
var orderMaster= _vasRepository.GetOrderDetails()
                         .Where(od => od.OrderMaster.OrganizationId != null &&
                                od.OrderId == od.OrderMaster.OrderId && 
                                od.OrderMaster.PaymentStatus == true && 
                                od.ValidityTill.Value >= currentdate)
                         .OrderByDescending(od => od.ValidityTill)
                         .Select(ord => ord.OrderMaster.Id.Value);

var updatedVacancyList = _repository.GetJobs()
                                    .Where(c => c.UpdatedDate != null && 
                                           updateFresh <= c.UpdatedDate)
                                    .Select(c => c.Id);

var orderLatestUser = _vasRepository.GetOrderDetails()
                                    .Where(od => od.OrderMaster.UserId != null && 
                                           od.OrderMaster.PaymentStatus == true && 
                                           freshUser <= od.ActivationDate && 
                                           od.ValidityTill.Value >= currentdate)
                                    .Select(c => c.OrderMaster.User.Id);
```

Then I check the count of those then assign to

```
List<int> lstMasterId = orderOrganization.ToList();
List<int>lstUpdatedJobsListId = updatedVacancyList.ToList();
List<int>lstUserListId= orderLatestUser.ToList();
```

Here i order the lists using query

```
Func<IQueryable<Job>, IOrderedQueryable<Job>> orderingFunc = query => 
{
    if (orderMaster.Count() > 0)
        return query.OrderByDescending(rslt => 
            lstOrganizationId.Contains(rslt.OrganizationId))                
              .ThenByDescending(rslt=>lstUserListId.Contains(rslt.User.Id))
              .ThenByDescending(rslt => lstUpdatedJobsListId.Contains(rslt.Id))
              .ThenByDescending(rslt => rslt.CreatedDate);

    else
        return query.OrderByDescending(rslt => rslt.CreatedDate);
};

            jobs = orderingFunc(jobs);
        }
```

I want to show the `lstUserListId` at top of the result.. How to do this?

Comment: I've tried to read this twice, and I'm still not able to understand what the problem is... Please, try to explain it more clearly

Comment: I want to show `lstUserListId` at top of the result